# Password-username <head> size

Tags: javascript, head

I have a problem with a password-username login form that I made with JavaScript. It's not the form itself, but it has such a big `<head>` that it takes up space.

Is there something I can add to it to keep it without it taking up space?

Comment: can you explain a bit more and give an example

Comment: What you mean big `<head>`? It's really unclear what is the problem.

Comment: When you reply please use `@` e.g. @namehere to notify otherwise we won't see your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're using embedded JS inside your HTML. I could be wrong from the ambiguity in the question.

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

And put all your JS inside of that file